# Is there a way to see the removed answers to a question?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

So I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867842) that was hard to communicate and understand.  However, [bdonlan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36723/bdonlan) did understand, and came up with an awesome answer.  We went back and forth and fleshed out the solution nicely...  but now when I look, that answer is gone!!  How might I re-read it?

As it stands, that question is just about useless now, because all the other 'answers' remaining are junk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a way. Continuously post high quality questions and answers until you attain 10k reputation. With a bit of effort, luck, and solid knowledge it'll take no more than two months when you start with 1 rep. Once you hit 10k, you'll have, among others, the [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) to see deleted answers.

Comment: With *a bit* of effort, luck, and solid knowledge? *No more than two months??*

Comment: @Chris: On Stackoverflow. Post 10 good quality answers per day in popular tags. With an average of 2 votes per answer, you're already on 200rep/day. 10k requires only 50 of such days, accepts and bounties not counted.

Answer (score 5):

That question has one deleted answer. [That answer's author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36723/bdonlan) wrote a [more-detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867842/you-can-promote-access-specification-through-inheritance-can-you-ever-demote/6867912#6867912) (which you accepted) to your same question.

I can only guess that he or she felt more comfortable starting a new answer from scratch.

Comment: That's the one and that is why.  You guys are good!